# Node.js and security and non-standard ports and a surly server admin

Tags: node.js, angularjs, security, ports

I am excited to use node with angular for our trends data. However, our server admin isn't too excited about it. He posed the following question:

So in order to use these services, the client would have to make a connection to these ports? If so, that doesn’t sound like a good idea to me. A lot of CUs firewall and/or filter non-standard outbound ports, so in addition to security considerations for incoming traffic, there’s the consideration that many of your clients may not be able to use whatever it is you’re trying to turn on. Is this some special service they’re trying to consume and would be willing to adjust their firewalls to access?

How does one answer this?

Comment: What are you trying to do that's so special?  If it's just a simple web application with socket.io, for example, you can have it served up on the standard HTTP or HTTPS port.  I don't see how that is any security risk.

Comment: Those two ports are reserved for Apache (I should have mentioned that). I am attempting to use port 1337 for nginx and 3000 for node. Perhaps I don't need these exposed to the web since they are acting as middleware (?)